# Amazon S3 - is it possible to display images?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

My mobile app uploads images into Amazon S3 bucket. Now I need to get URL where image is displayed, not downloaded. Is it possible to do that? Thank you for idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it can be done by setting meta-data in the S3 AWS Management Console - [ `Content-Type : image/png` or `Content-Type : image/jpg` ] depending on the image format.

Once you have done this, the browser will render the image instead of downloading that.

Check out [Object Key and Metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html) for more info.